# Interpretation of output of mma package in R

Tags: r

I was exploring the "mma" library in R for multiple mediator analysis. The data.org() function in the package performs two tests for identification of the mediator variables. Some of the p-values for this test are showing as NA.
The example present in this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mma/vignettes/MMAvignette.html also has p-values as NA.
Why are the p-values showing as NA?